# cacert option and process substitution

Tags: curl

When I do

```
$ curl ... --cacert <(cat intermediate1.pem intermediate2.pem root.pem) ...
```

I see the error:

```
* NSS error -5978
* Closing connection #0
* Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

So first I have to do:

```
$ cat intermediate1.pem intermediate2.pem root.pem >ca.pem
```

and then I can do

```
$ curl ... --cacert ca.pem ...
```

But why does `--cacert <(cat ...)` does not work? I can use `<(cat ...)` with the `comm` command for example in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem depends on the version of **curl**.

[Here's a commit](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/191ffd07082322cdfd4ca4581f39160166534405) that added support for FIFO (which is a **bash** *process substitution*) in the `--cert` flag.

So, according to tags in curl repo, this problem present in library until **curl-7.65** version.

Comment: We have curl 7.19.7.

Comment: Prior to **7.65** only regular file accepted as an argument to the `--cert` flag. Even symlink will not work.